# what method can i use in ENTERPRISE WSDL for creating incident?

Tags: community, soap-api, wsdl, wsdl2apex, enterprise-wsdl

is there any seperate method available for creating incident in ENTERPRISE WSDL of remedyforce?

Any suggestion regarding this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell [remedyforce](http://www.salesforce.com/remedyforce/overview/) is produced by BMC.

From the page [Remedyforce API - Webervices, Wsdl](https://communities.bmc.com/message/499396)

> Log in as a System Administrator then go to **Setup | Develop | API**. On the API WSDL page you may then choose which WSDL to generate and download. I typically choose **Enterprise WSDL**.
>
> You can then develop any web service client you need for interfacing with Salesforce / Remedyforce in Java, C#, etc.
>
> Check out [Salesforce's SOAP API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/) too.

On the same page:

> You can define methods in that class that take a **BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c** object as a parameter.

So, assuming the user that generated the Enterprise WSDL has access to incident and the Enterprise WSDL was generated after the managed package was installed you should be able to [create()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm) the required records. You will be creating `BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c` records.